# How can use sPageNextDisabled in Jquery datatable 1.9?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

I have a datatable having 12 columns.

```
oTable = $('#NotificationsTable').dataTable({
    "bDestroy": true,
    "bFilter": true,
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "bPaginate": true,
    "bsorting": true,
    "iDisplayStart": 0,
    "aLengthMenu": [[25, 50, 100, -1], [25, 50, 100, "All"]],
    "iDisplayLength": 25,
    "bLengthChange": true,
    "bServerSide": true,

    "sAjaxSource": "URL",

    "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {

        aoData.push({ "name": "param", "value": "page" }
            );
    },

    "aoColumns": [
        { "mData": "Col0", "sClass": "center" }, 
        { "mData": "Col1", "sClass": "center" }, 
        { "mData": "Col2", "sClass": "center" },
        { "mData": "Col3", "sClass": "center wrapword" }, 
        { "mData": "Col4", "sClass": "center" },
        { "mData": "Col5", "sClass": "center" }, 
         { "mData": "Col6", "sClass": "center" }, 
        { "mData": "Col7", "sClass": "center" }, 
         { "mData": "Col8", "sClass": "center" }, 
        { "mData": "Col9", "sClass": "center" }, 
        { "mData": "Col10", "sClass": "center" }, 
        { "mData": "Col11", "bSortable": true }
    ],
    "fnInitComplete": function (oSettings, json) {
        //Some function
    },


    }
});

oTable .columnFilter({
    sPlaceHolder: "head:after", aoColumns: [
                     { type: "text" }, { type: "text" }, { type: "text" }, { type: "text" },
                       { type: "text" }, null, { type: "text" }, { type: "text" },
                       { type: "text" }, { type: "text" }, { type: "text" }, { type: "text" }
    ]

});
```

Here I want to disable the NEXT button of the datatable when "ALL" entries are shown.

FYI: I am having one row already in the datatable but I never wanted to show that to the user.

Comment: The `Next` button is disabled automatically when the user select "All" in the length menu. This is default in both 1.9.x and 1.10.x versions.

Comment: Yes..but as I told, I have to do it manually given my situation.

Answer (score 1):

The Next button always have the id `<table_id>_next`, the length menu `<table_id>_length`. in dataTables 1.9.x there is individual CSS classes for each button's enabled or disabled mode. Toggle those classes when length value is -1, the value of `All`. Finally unbind the Next page event from the button.

```js
$('select[name="NotificationsTable_length"]').on('change', function() {
    var $nextButton = $("#NotificationsTable_next");
    if ($(this).val() == -1) {
        $nextButton.toggleClass('paginate_disabled_next');
        $nextButton.unbind('click');
    } else {
        $nextButton.toggleClass('paginate_enabled_next');
    }        
}).trigger('change');
```

1.9.4 demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/stgLt59d/**

---

In dataTables 1.10.x there is just a single `.disabled` class targeting all the pagination buttons.

```
$('select[name="NotificationsTable_length"]').on('change', function() {
    var $nextButton = $("#NotificationsTable_next");
    if ($(this).val() == -1) {
        $nextButton.addClass('disabled');
        $nextButton.unbind('click');
    } else {
        $nextButton.removeClass('disabled');
    }        
}).trigger('change');
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/20q6adng/**

Comment: @davidkonrad.Thanks. It works when we change the dropdown value to all as we are adding this on change. But whenevr tthe page loads and the value is "All", then it doesn't.

Comment: @Prasanna, You are right, the event will be triggerend only when the user selects a new item. Just trigger the `change` event immediately (see updated code examples) upon pageload.

Comment: Thanks @davidkonrad.  But on load, I tried to attach as you mentioned. It doesn't work when page loads..But yes, it works perfectly when change event is fired. +1 for that.